# Empty text in Xpath

Tags: python, xpath, web-scraping

I have written this line of code for creating a list through XPath

```
classes=tree.xpath('//a[@class="pathm"]/../../../../../td[3]/font/text()')
```

It creates a list.Their are also items containing empty text.The list does not contain them.It contains only non empty values.I want to take empty string in the list wherever their is no text. Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get only `//font` and later use loop to get text or own text if there is empty text (or rather `None`)

```
import lxml.html

data = '''
<font>A</font>
<font></font>
<font>C</font>
'''

tree = lxml.html.fromstring(data)

fonts = tree.xpath('//font')

result = [x.text if x.text else '' for x in fonts]

print(result)
```

---

If you don't know how list comprehension works - it do this

```
result = []

for x in fonts:
    if x.text: # not None
        result.append(x.text)
    else:
        result.append('')

print(result)
```